# Running react-native run-ios is success. but not launch simulator

Tags: ios, react-native

I've been using ReactNative in Windows. Android is perfect and now it has to build on the iPhone and give ipa to clients.

However, even if you run counter-native run-ios after updating the code yesterday, the app will not be launched on the simulator.

I started a new project because I thought there might be a problem with my project, and then I ran a counter-native run-ios, but I failed.

The terminal is output as a successful build, but there is no response to the simulator.
App is not installed.
Somebody please help me.

react-native version is 0.59.9

Images are run on terminals and simulators.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, in my case I was in sudo mode. When I turned it back to normal mode, it showed up on the IOS simulator as an app.

Answer (score 0):

As in latest react-native version 0.60.0 + they have fixed too many problems which are with integration of latest xCode version.
Please do the following to achieve

1. Upgrade react-native version to 0.60.0 or +
2. rm -rf node_modules/&& yarn install && react-native link
3. cd ios and then pod install

Close the bundle and run(Cmd+ r) from xCode